# How to install ffmpeg on rhel7

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos, rhel7

whein i installing ffmpeg on RHEL,i got an error like this

> ```
> > Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
> >            Requires: libopenal.so.1()(64bit) Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
> >            Requires: libva.so.1()(64bit) Error: Package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
> >            Requires: libvdpau.so.1()(64bit) Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
> >            Requires: libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit) Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
> >            Requires: libass.so.5()(64bit) Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
> >            Requires: libschroedinger-1.0.so.0()(64bit) Error: Package: ffmpeg-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
> >            Requires: libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit
> ```

RHEL7 is not registered.

Comment: See [FFMPEG - why do I end up with old version after installing?](https://superuser.com/a/1372482/110524)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install ffmpeg on your rhel7 server using RPM.

```
sudo yum install -y https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y ffmpeg
```

After the install verify ffmpeg version

```
ffmpeg -version
```

For more information check the below link.

[ffmpeg basic examples](https://etechoptions.com/2020/06/06/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-rhel-centos7/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use one of the 3rd-party repositories that offer multimedia packages, such as [negativo17](https://negativo17.org/multimedia/) (which needs the regular [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository enabled):

`# yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
 # yum-config-manager --add-repo https://negativo17.org/repos/epel-multimedia.repo
 # yum install ffmpeg`

Btw, an unregistered installation of RHEL isn't a good idea -- no security updates, no easy installation of software, etc. I would suggest either buying a subscription, or using a free alternative, such as CentOS.

Comment: its not fixing my issue.

Comment: Well, please, try the suggested solution. If you're getting the same error, you're still using Nux Desktop, which, apparently, has some problems for you. The issue could also be related to your RHEL not being subscribed. Provide more info.